# GWT using setAttribute in IE7 from inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, gwt, iframe, internet-explorer-7, setattribute

I have a GWT web app. When I use

```
 element.setAttribute("style", myAttributeList);
```

**it perfectly works for IE7** (*)

Now comes the tricky part. I embed my web app, served at *http://www.myGWTApp.com*, in a web page with a different domain using the typical *iframe* tag:

```
<iframe src="http://www.myGWTApp.com" height="194" width="600"></iframe>
```

As a result of this the app works perfectly well except for every **element.setAttribute( , )** that I have in my code, which **doesn't work at all**.

So, GWT has lost its magic when running from inside an IFRAME...

Do you know any way to solve this? Perhaps using JSNI?

Thanks!

**Edit**
The embedding page contains the following HTML tag:

```
<meta content="IE=EmulateIE7" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

so, the app is running in IE7.

> (*) I'm aware that the JS setAttribute is broken for IE7 but
>   apparently GWT does a good job and isolates Java programmers from that
>   issue (when no iframes are involved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the container page and your app in the iframes are both running in `standars` mode.  Also check that the host page doesn't have any `X-UA-Compatible` meta-tag

Comment: The embedding page is running with the following tag *<meta content="IE=EmulateIE7" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">*, so the app is running in IE7. That's why specifically asked about using setAttribute in IE7...

Comment: are both running in standards mode?

Comment: Hmm, you lost me there. How can I be sure that both are running in standards mode? I have tried adding the tag *<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>* or the tag *<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >* to my app in the iframe and it does not work

Comment: The first line in both pages should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: The embedded page is running in stardards mode. The container page has the <!DOCTYPE html> tag, but because document mode is by default IE7, it appears commented in the DOM. You can check it yourself: http://greenweaving.blogspot.com/2012/12/test2.html, the embedded page is the diagram, which is not able to render properly when document mode is IE7 (which is by default the case).

Comment: The website seems to work for me in either ie7 and ie8, container Yep, page and iframe are running in standars mode and it seems to work in my virtual machines with ie7 and ie8,  how can I see the problem?. BTW do you have the option to modify the gwt code? because instead of setting the attribure style you could modify individual style properties (which is the normal way in gwt)

Comment: Setting the attribute through getStyle().setProperty()?, of course, why didn't I think of that!?! I just tested it and it works!! You made my day, thank you!!